# prove $\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2}\frac{(-1)^k}{6n+5-k}\binom{6n+5-k}{k}=\frac{1}{6n+5}$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I want to
prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2}\frac{(-1)^k}{6n+5-k}\binom{6n+5-k}{k}=\frac{1}{6n+5}$$
Let $\displaystyle f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n+1)/2\rfloor}\binom{n-k+1}{k}x^{n-k}$,
 then we have a recurrence relation 
$$f_n(x)=xf_{n-1}(x)+xf_{n-2}(x) \quad ; \quad f_1(x)=x+1,\quad f_0(x)=1$$

Hence, $$\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2}\frac{(-1)^k}{6n+5-k}\binom{6n+5-k}{k}=\int_{-1}^0f_{6n+4}(x)dx$$

What will I do from here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheSecondKind.html) have the following closed form:

$$ U_n(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-r}{r}(-1)^r (2x)^{n-2r} \tag{1} $$
hence:

$$ x^{n-1}\,U_n(x/2) = \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-r}{r}(-1)^r (x)^{2n-2r-1} \tag{2} $$

and:
$$ S_n=\sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-r}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{n-r} = 2\int_{0}^{1}x^{n-1} U_n(x/2)\,dx. \tag{3} $$
By substituting $x=2\cos\theta$, the last integral turns into an elementary integral and we get:
$$\boxed{ \sum_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n-r}{r}\frac{(-1)^r}{n-r} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}}\tag{4}$$
for any $n\equiv \pm1\pmod{6}$. As an alternative, we may use the generating function for Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind, by replacing $x$ with $x/2$, then $t$ with $xt$. $S_n$ then becomes the coefficient of $t^n$ in a simple analytic function.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to prove that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2} \frac{(-1)^k}{6n+5-k}
{6n+5-k\choose k} = \frac{1}{6n+5}.$$

This means we must show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2} (-1)^k \frac{6n+5}{6n+5-k}
{6n+5-k\choose k} = 1.$$

The LHS is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2} (-1)^k \left(1+\frac{k}{6n+5-k}\right)
{6n+5-k\choose k}$$

This has two components, the first is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2} (-1)^k {6n+5-k\choose k}$$

and the second is

$$\sum_{k=0}^{3n+2} (-1)^k \frac{k}{6n+5-k}
{6n+5-k\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^{3n+2} (-1)^k \frac{k}{6n+5-k}
\frac{6n+5-k}{k} {6n+4-k\choose k-1}
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^{3n+2} (-1)^k {6n+4-k\choose k-1}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{3n+1} (-1)^{k+1} {6n+3-k\choose k}.$$

Now for the first sum we introduce

$${6n+5-k\choose k} = {6n+5-k\choose 6n+5-2k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{6n+6-2k}} (1+z)^{6n+5-k} \; dz.$$

This vanishes for $k\ge 3n+3$ as required. We get for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{6n+6}} (1+z)^{6n+5} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k \frac{z^{2k}}{(1+z)^k}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{6n+6}} (1+z)^{6n+5} 
\frac{1}{1+z^2/(1+z)}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{6n+6}} (1+z)^{6n+6} 
\frac{1}{1+z+z^2}
\; dz.$$

Using  the  substitution $z/(1+z)=w$  (which  is  a linear  fractional
transformation that  maps circles to circles) so  that $z=w/(1-w)$ and
$dz=1/(1-w)^2\; dw$ we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{6n+6}}
\frac{1}{1+w/(1-w)+w^2/(1-w)^2}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{6n+6}}
\frac{1}{(1-w)^2+w(1-w)+w^2}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{6n+6}}
\frac{1}{1-w+w^2}
\; dw.$$

In the substitution  into the first integral we  have used the fact
that the image circle of  $|z|=\epsilon$ can be deformed to obtain the
circle $|w|=\gamma$.

Now we  can solve this by  inspection having a  linear recurrence with
constant coefficients whose  solution is periodic but we  may also use
that  $1-w+w^2 =  (w-\rho)(w-1/\rho)$ with  $\rho=-\exp(2\pi  i/3)$ so
that with partial fractions by residues we get

$$\frac{1}{1-w+w^2}
= \frac{1}{2\rho-1}\frac{1}{w-\rho}
+ \frac{1}{2/\rho-1}\frac{1}{w-1/\rho}
\\ = \frac{1}{2\rho^2-\rho}\frac{1}{w/\rho-1}
+ \frac{1}{2/\rho^2-1/\rho}\frac{1}{w\rho-1}.$$

We are extracting the coefficient  on $[w^{6n+5}]$ and with the powers
of $\rho$ being  periodic with period six (period  of $\exp(\pi i)$ is
two  and period  of $\exp(2\pi  i/3)$ is  three, lcm  is six)  this is
$[w^5]$ so we get

$$-\frac{1}{2\rho^2-\rho}\frac{1}{\rho^5}
- \frac{1}{2/\rho^2-1/\rho}\frac{1}{(1/\rho)^5}.$$

Using periodicity we get

$$-\frac{1}{2\rho-1} - \frac{1}{2/\rho-1}
= -\frac{2/\rho-1+2\rho-1}{(2\rho-1)(2/\rho-1)}
= -\frac{2\rho^2-2\rho+2}{\rho(2\rho-1)(2/\rho-1)} =0,$$

because the  numerator is zero here, and  we get zero as  the value of
the first component being sought. Continuing with the second component
we see  the parameter three  takes the place  of five and there  is an
extra sign present and we find

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{6n+4}} (1+z)^{6n+4} 
\frac{1}{1+z+z^2}
\; dz.$$

The substitution with $w$ now yields

$$-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{6n+4}}
\frac{1}{1-w+w^2}
\; dw.$$

This is the coefficient on $[w^3]$ and we obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\rho^2-\rho}\frac{1}{\rho^3}
+ \frac{1}{2/\rho^2-1/\rho}\frac{1}{(1/\rho)^3}.$$

With $2\rho^5-\rho^4 = 2/\rho - 1/\rho^2 = (2\rho-1)/\rho^2
= (2\rho-1)/(\rho-1)$ the inverse is $1/2 - 1/(2\rho-1)/2$
and we find

$$1 - \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2\rho-1} -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2/\rho-1}
= 1$$

as we already evaluated this term. The two components add to $0+1$ and
we have the claim.

**Remark.** We can avoid  the somewhat tedious algebra by appealing
to basic  recurrences as pointed out earlier.  The generating function
yields the recurrence $a_{n+2} = a_{n+1} - a_{n}.$ The constant term is

$$\left.\frac{1}{1-w+w^2}\right|_{w=0} = 1$$

and the term on $[w]$ is

$$\left.-\frac{2w-1}{(1-w+w^2)^2}\right|_{w=0} = 1.$$

We then use the recurrence until it becomes periodic, getting

$$1,1,0,-1,-1,0,1,1,\ldots$$

and  we have  the  required values  with  minimal effort.  One of  the
guiding  design  parameters  here  was  not to  bring  in  algebra  of
instantiated complex numbers.

Comment: Instructive answer (+1)

Comment: This answer would benefit from replacing $6n+5$ by a parameter. I will leave it as is for now.

Comment: Yes, you're right.